# JS event listeners disappear due to wp plugin conflict

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I wrote a little [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-rating/) for WordPress. Today some user reported that it conflicts with another [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). Thing is, if I enable this second plugin, all js event listeners that were added by my plugin magically disappear as if they were never there to begin with.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Try loading the plugin first, then your files.

Comment: You should post the relevant code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Oh if I knew even approximately what part of code could be causing this, I would, but I honestly have no clue. So I'd like to know what generally could cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, this was stupid. Wrapping event listeners `$( document ).ready(function() {}` solved issue. Yeah, I should have done it that way to begin with, don't know why I didn't.